# Efficient way to find eigenvalues of the matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I have a matrix $A = (a_{ij})$, $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, where $a_{ij} = i + j\pmod{n}$. I want to find it's eigenvalues, but it's really hard to count it's determinant (to find triangular matrix). Is there an easier way? I noticed that the sum of elements is equal in each line, but I'm not sure can it help or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer for $\ n\ $ from $2$ to $10$.  While some patterns are evident, they seem difficult to generalise.

In general,
$$
A_n=\pmatrix{2&3&4&\cdots&0&1\\
             3&4&5&\cdots&1&2\\
             \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots\\
              0&1&2&\cdots&n-2&n-1\\
              1&2&3&\cdots&n-1&0}\ .
$$
As the OP mentioned, each row of this matrix sums to the same value, namely $\ {n\choose 2}\ $, so this is an eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector $\ \pmatrix{1\\1\\ 
\vdots\\1}\ $.

For $\ n=2,3,\dots,10\ $,  we have
\begin{align}
\det\left(xI_2-A_2\right)&=x^2-1\\
&=(x-1)(x+1)\\
\det\left(xI_3-A_3\right)&=x^3-3x^2-3x+9\\
&=(x-3)(x^2-3)\\
\det\left(xI_4-A_4\right)&=x^4-4x^3-20x^2+32x+96\\
&=(x-6)(x^3+2x^2-2^3x-2^4)\\
&=(x-6)(x^2-8)(x+2)\\
\det\left(xI_5-A_5\right)&=x^5-10x^4-25x^3+250x^2+125x-1250\\
&=(x-10)(x^4-5^2x^2+5^3)\\
\det\left(xI_6-A_6\right)&=x^6-12x^5-93x^4+576x^3+2592x^2\\
&\hspace{2em}-5184x-19440\\
&=(x-15)(x+3)(x^2-36)(x^2-12)\\\
\det\left(xI_7-A_7\right)&=x^7-21x^6-98x^5+2058x^4+2401x^3\\
&\hspace{2em}-50421x^2-16807x+352947\\
&=(x-21)(x^6-2\cdot7^2x^4+7^4x^2-7^5)\\
\det\left(xI_8-A_8\right)&=x^8-24x^7-272x^6+3840x^5+24064x^4\\
&\hspace{2em}-147456x^3-753664x^2+1572864x+7340032\\
&=(x-28)(x^2-32)(x+4)(x^4-2^7x^2+2^{11})\\
\det\left(xI_9-A_9\right)&=x^9-36x^8-270x^7+9720x^6+19683x^5-708588x^4\\
&\hspace{2em}-531441x^3+19131876x^2+4783969x-17218688\\
&=(x-36)(x^2-27)(x^6-3\cdot9^2x^4+2\cdot9^4x^2-3\cdot9^5)\\
\det\left(xI_{10}-A_{10}\right)&=x^{10}-40x^9-625x^8+16000x^7+132000x^6-1680000x^5\\
&\hspace{2em}-1105\cdot10^4x^4+64\cdot10^6x^3+38\cdot10^7x^2-8\cdot10^8x\\
&\hspace{2em}-45\cdot10^8\\
&=(x-45)(x+5)(x^4-10^2x^2+2\cdot10^3)(x^4-3\cdot10^3x+10^4)\ .
\end{align}

Thus, the eigenvalues are,
\begin{align}
\text{of } A_2:&-1,1\ ,\\
\text{of } A_3:&\pm\sqrt{3}, 3\ ,\\
\text{of } A_4:&\pm\sqrt{8},-2,6\ ,\\
\text{of } A_5:&\pm\sqrt{\frac{25-5\sqrt{5}}{2}},\pm\sqrt{\frac{25+5\sqrt{5}}{2}},10\ ,\\
\text{of } A_6:&-3,\pm2\sqrt{3},\pm6,15\, \\
\text{of } A_7:&\pm\sqrt{\omega_1}, \pm\sqrt{\omega_2},\pm\sqrt{\omega_3},21\ ,\\
\text{of } A_8:&-4,\pm4\sqrt{2},\pm4\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{2}},\pm4\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{2}}, 28\ ,\\
\text{of } A_9:&\pm3\sqrt{3},\pm\sqrt{\xi_1}, \pm\sqrt{\xi_2},\pm\sqrt{\xi_3}, 36\ ,\\
\text{of } A_{10}:&-5,\pm\sqrt{50-10\sqrt{5}},\pm\sqrt{50+10\sqrt{5}}, \pm10\sqrt{\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}},\pm10\sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}}, 45\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ \omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3\ $ are the roots of the cubic  $\ x^3-2\cdot7^2x^2+7^4x-7^5\ $, and $\ \xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3\ $ the roots of the cubic $\ x^3-3\cdot9^2x^2+2\cdot9^4x-3\cdot9^5\ $ (all of which are positive real numbers).

The main feature of these results that stand out for me is that all the characteristic polynomials split over $\ \mathbb{Z}\ $ into factors of the form $\ x+a, x^2+b, x^4+ cx^2+d,\ $ or $\ x^6+ex^4+fx^2+g\ $.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave my answer below just in case anyone finds it useful, but I misread the question and missed that the entries are $i+j \boldsymbol{\bmod n}$, what I say below applies to the matrix $(i+j)_{n\times n}$.

---

This matrix will have $0$ as an eigenvalue with multiplicity $n-2$, since its rank is always $2$.

The remaining two eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$ satisfy $$\lambda+\mu=\operatorname{tr}(A)=2 + \cdots + 2n=n(n+1),$$ and the product $\lambda\mu$ is the coefficient of $x^{n-2}$ in the characteristic polynomial (by, say, Viète's formulæ), which you can show to be $\frac{n^2}{12}(n^2-1)$.

From this, you can solve simultaneously to get that the eigenvalues are 
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{n^2(n+1)(n+2)}{6}},$$
each with multiplicity $1$, and $0$ with multiplicity $n-2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I haven't quite understood why matrix has eigenvalue 0 with multiplicity $n - 2$?

Comment: Since the rank of the matrix is $2$, it has a null space of dimension $n-2$ (by the [dimension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)). It follows that there are $n-2$ linearly independent vectors $v$ such that $Av=0$, so that they span the nullspace.

Comment: But how it's rank can be 2 if its determinant isn't 0?

Comment: The determinant *is* zero. It's the product of the eigenvalues.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera  For example, matrix with n = 3 looks like
  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 \\
  1 & 2 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}
 and its determinant isn't zero

Comment: @Ronald S Merritt Yes, you're right. I accepted the statement that the matrix has rank 2 at face value without checking it. On closer examination, it turns out that the statement is false, as your example shows.

Comment: @RonaldSMerritt You'll have to excuse me, I missed the $\mod n$ part!